# Pythonic Way to Get Unique Neighboring Integers in an Ordered List

Tags: python, loops, search, integer

Given an ordered integer list, return the largest integer less than N and smallest integer greater than N.
If there is none for one, just print "X".

Comment: You need to loop through the list, not just get the first and last elements.

Comment: Since it is an ordered list, I assumed that if `n` is less than the first element (which SHOULD be the smallest), then we can conclude that there is no largest element less than `n`, same thing for the last element.

Comment: My bad, that's supposed to be `li`, updated it. It checks if `checkNum` is present in the li. If not, it decrements this variable until there is.

My algorithm does not have to go through the whole list. It only tries values close to `n`. If there exists, then it can be concluded that these values are the ones that we're looking for.

Comment: A simplistic approach could be to first loop over the list and set an `lt` variable if the element is less than `n`. Then do the same for the reversed list, setting `gt` if the element is greater than `n`. You could then extend that to short-circuit the loop by `break`ing.

Comment: Since the list is ordered, you can use binary search.

Comment: Binary search is O(log n) instead of O(n).

Comment: Does the ordered list have only one of each number?

Comment: Nope, there could be duplicates. This problem has been solved already, but feel free to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is the fastest solution possible.

```
def binary_search(arr, x):
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    mid = 0
    lm = -1
    while low <= high:
        lm = mid
        mid = (high + low) // 2
        if arr[mid] < x:
            low = mid + 1
        elif arr[mid] > x:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            return mid
        if lm == mid:break
    return mid

def find_next_bigger(arr,n,i):
    while i < len(arr):
          if arr[i] > n:
              return arr[i]
          i += 1
    return arr[i] if i < len(arr) else "X"

def find_next_smaller(arr, n,i):
        while i >= 0:
            if arr[i] < n:
                return arr[i]
            i -= 1
        return arr[i] if i > 0 else "X"

def solution(arr, n):
    if n > arr[-1]:
        return arr[-1], "X"
    if arr[0] > n:
          return "X", arr[0]
    i = binary_search(arr, n)
    bigger = find_next_bigger(arr, n, i)
    smaller = find_next_smaller(arr,n,i)
    return smaller, bigger
```

Comment: Tried this, and it passed the 1 sec requirement. I guess it is the fastest of all discussed solutions. Well done!

Comment: not as fast as the `bisect` module which is coded in C

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go!  Your code is especially slow with big number differences.  e.g. `[0, 752,15000,670000,37452846,3826848827,10000000000]` with the number argument `40000000`.  I suppose you could also do a binary search type of thing if you wanted *reeeallly huuuuge* lists, but those are super annoying to make.

```
def solution(list_, n):
    l = list(filter(lambda p: p != n, sorted(list_[:])))
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if x > n: break
    else: return [l[-1], "X"]
    return [l[i-1], l[i]] if i else ["X", l[i]]
```

Comment: I tried this, it's still slower than the 1 sec requirement. I guess you're right with the binary search approach, it might be faster.

Comment: Take the middle of the list, check it against the number, if number>middle, check 3/4 mark of list, if number<middle check 1/4 mark of list.  Continue.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a bit slower than Galih Indra's approach? In his code, you just take the elements beside n and return it. No more searching.

Comment: Galih Indra's approach only works if n is an element in the list.  If so, this problem becomes extremely simple.  As you told it, it is not a requirement that n is in the list.  If that is incorrect, I'll write a function for you in 2 minutes that has a crazy simple time complexity.

Comment: In his algorithm, he appends `n` to the list if `n` is not in the list, then he gets the neighboring numbers. Is there a loophole with that approach?

Comment: I missed that.  Anyway, his program is slower than you want because he calls the .sort method which is in O(n^2) time.  The binary search method is in O(log2(n)) time, so it's much faster at finding where n should be.

Comment: The built-in .sort method runs in O(nlog(n)) time as far as I know, but anyway, How do you implement binary search in this problem?

Comment: Refer to my other answer.  It is literally the fastest solution possible (considering the method of finding the solution, not the literal code), unless someone has come up with a new searching algorithm faster than O(log2(n)) (they haven't).

Answer (score 1):

Hope you understanding this

```
li = [2, 4, 6, 8]
n = 9

#l for largest int lesser than n, s for smallest int greater than n
l = 'X'
s = 'X'

#insert n to list and ordered it
li.append(n)
li.sort()

#get the index of n in the list
index_n = li.index(n)

#if the n is not the smallest value in list, we assign the value before n to l
if index_n > 0:
    l = str(li[index_n - 1])

#if the n is not the greatest value in list, we assign the value after n to s
if index_n < len(li)-1:
    s = str(li[index_n + 1])
    
print(l,s)
```

Comment: I understood your approach, but I tried it and it's still slow. I think the problem is caused by the number of cases. The maximum possible test cases is 25000 (according to the compiler), program has to run 25000 `n`'s with the same list. I modified your code to accept many test cases. Please check the main post.

Comment: The modified code still doesn't cut the 1 second requirement.

Answer (score 1):

No need to overthink it; this was surprisingly fast on my system (some modern laptop i7) and feels very Pythonic

```py
# /usr/bin/env python3

# create ordered list of values
# NOTE that this need not be included in the algorithm time
l = list(range(0, 25000*3, 3))
print(len(l))

# pick some large n outside of the list l
n = 1000000

# try to find the min and max before and after N
try:
    a = max(x for x in l if x < n)
except ValueError:
    a = 'X'

try:
    b = min(x for x in l if x > n)
except ValueError:
    b = 'X'

print(a,b)
```

```sh
% time python3 so64964821.py
25000
74997 X
python3 so64964821.py  0.02s user 0.01s system 87% cpu 0.036 total
```

Comment: Tried this, and yeah it's really fast, but we have to consider multiple test cases in the algorithm time, in our exercise, the maximum number of `n`'s is `25000`, which means that I will iterate the code 25000 times with different `n` values. All of this process must be under 1 second. Since your code runs the fastest,  I updated my main code based off of your code but modified to accept multiple `n`'s. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard library keeps things simple-- and library methods are generally well-optimised and fast. The `bisect` module ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)) has what you want:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
sorted_list = list(range(0, 50000, 2))
insertion_point = bisect_left(sorted_list, 15001)
below = sorted_list[insertion_point - 1]
above = sorted_list[insertion_point]
print(below, above)

$ python bis.py
15000 15002
```

`bisect_left` uses a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the "insertion point"-- the index where you'd insert this new number in the list to maintain the current sort order. That is exactly what you need to find your number's neighbors.

That's a start. You'll need a bit more logic to print 'X' if your number falls outside the range of integers in the sorted list.

Source code for `bisect_left` can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/bisect.py) which is worth a look. Beautifully simple.